# Resizeable quadratic grid

Tags: javafx-8

I would like to display a quadratic `GridPane` inside a window. The window can have every possible size and normally width and height are not equal. Anyway I would like to display the `GridPane` as square centered like this:

[image: width greater than height]

respectively

[image: height greater than width]

Ideally there is a configurable padding around the square. The pictures are taken from a canvas approach, but I want to switch to standard controls. Can anyone give me some hints how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve an squared layout for your grid for any resolution of your window is rescaling it to use the maximum size of the window (after some padding), while keeping the squared size.

Instead of a `GridPane`, a simple `Group` is more flexible for moving its children, though it requires manual layouting of them.

This simple snippet is based on the JavaFX implementation of the 2048 game you can find [here](https://github.com/brunoborges/fx2048). It uses styleable rectangles to create a grid, and over them the 'tiles' are added. To find out more about styling, layouting or tile movement, go to the refered link.

```
private static final int NUM_CELLS = 15;
private static final int CELL_SIZE = 50;
private static final int TILE_SIZE = CELL_SIZE-15;
private final static int MARGIN = 20;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // create background square grid
    Group gridGroup = new Group();
    IntStream.range(0,NUM_CELLS).boxed().forEach(i->
        IntStream.range(0,NUM_CELLS).boxed().forEach(j->{
            Rectangle cell = new Rectangle(i * CELL_SIZE, j * CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE);
            cell.setFill(Color.WHEAT);
            cell.setStroke(Color.GREY);
            gridGroup.getChildren().add(cell);
        })
    );
    // Add grid to board
    Group board = new Group(gridGroup);

    // add random tiles to board
    IntStream.range(0,NUM_CELLS).boxed().forEach(i->
        IntStream.range(0,NUM_CELLS).boxed().forEach(j->{
            if(i==j || NUM_CELLS-i-1==j){
                Label label = new Label();
                label.setMinSize(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                label.setPrefSize(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                label.setMaxSize(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE);
                label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red; -fx-background-radius: 50");
                label.setLayoutX((i+0.5)*CELL_SIZE-TILE_SIZE/2);
                label.setLayoutY((j+0.5)*CELL_SIZE-TILE_SIZE/2);
                board.getChildren().add(label);
            }
        })
    );

    Bounds gameBounds = board.getLayoutBounds();

    StackPane root = new StackPane(board);

    // Listener to rescale and center the board
    ChangeListener<Number> resize = (ov, v, v1) -> {
        double scale = Math.min((root.getWidth() - MARGIN) / gameBounds.getWidth(), 
                                (root.getHeight() - MARGIN) / gameBounds.getHeight());
        board.setScaleX(scale);
        board.setScaleY(scale);
        board.setLayoutX((root.getWidth() - gameBounds.getWidth()) / 2d);
        board.setLayoutY((root.getHeight() - gameBounds.getHeight()) / 2d);
    };
    root.widthProperty().addListener(resize);
    root.heightProperty().addListener(resize);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    // Maximum size of window
    Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    double factor = Math.min(visualBounds.getWidth() / (gameBounds.getWidth() + MARGIN),
            visualBounds.getHeight() / (gameBounds.getHeight() + MARGIN));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth((gameBounds.getWidth() + MARGIN) * factor);
    primaryStage.setHeight((gameBounds.getHeight() + MARGIN) * factor);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

And this is how it will look like after some window resizing:

[image: Grid]

Comment: Sorry for the late answer and accepting. The only flaw is that this solution produces an `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = JavaFX Application Thread` when you perform a resize and close the app afterwards. It is ok though when you just run and close it.

Comment: Hmm... I don't have such exception. Just running my code? Have a look at the link posted on my answer, you'll find a fully working application.

Comment: Occurs only when maximizing it and closing it afterwards (on a macbook).

Comment: On Windows it doesn't happen. Please try the app in the link and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Forget it, I will try to figure it out myself. Thanks for your help.